# Why is PageSpeed API returning a 429 Rate Limit error on the first request?

Tags: google-api, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I'm currently working on a program that consumes the PageSpeed API, specifically without an API key because [the official documentation mentions not needing one if you limit requests to 2 per minute](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/get-started). The program itself will make multiple requests, but besides there already being time between the requests I also put in a 2 second wait time, so it will never get above 1 requests per second. However, the first request I perform today immediately gives me a 429 Rate Limit error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 429,
    "message": "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Queries' and limit 'Queries per minute' of service 'pagespeedonline.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:583797351490'.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Queries' and...)
```

Does anybody know why this is happening, and the response is mentioning a project number that obviously has nothing to do with me since I haven't used an API key?

To eliminate my program as the source of the issue I have manually made requests to PageSpeed API with Postman. At random times I get the same 429 Rate Limit error despite not having made any earlier requests for over an hour, and always less then 1 per **minute** on average.